# Why can't I use the getFixed method at the arraylist? How can I make it work?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class MainFile{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<TypeExpences> listOfTypes = new ArrayList<TypeExpences>();
    Water waterExp = new Water(0, "fafasd", 10, "cubic meters", 2, 1);
    listOfTypes.add(waterExp);
    System.out.println((listOfTypes.get(0)).getFixed());
    }
}

public class Water extends UseExpences{
    int pricePer2;  
    public Water(int kod, String descr, int fixed, String unit, int 
     pricePer, int pricePer2){
    super(kod, descr, fixed, unit, pricePer);
    this.pricePer2 = pricePer2;
    }
   public int getFixed(){
   return super.getFixedPrice(fixedPrice);
   }
}

public class UseExpences extends TypeExpences{
    protected int fixedPrice;
    protected String unitOfMeasurement;
    protected int pricePerMeasurementUnit;

    public UseExpences(int kod, String descr, int fixed, String unit, int 
     pricePer){
        super(kod, descr);
        fixedPrice = fixed;
        unitOfMeasurement = unit;
        pricePerMeasurementUnit = pricePer;
    }

    public int getFixedPrice(int fixedPrice){
        return fixedPrice;
    }
}

public class TypeExpences {
    protected int code;
    protected String description;
    public TypeExpences(int kod, String descr){
        code = kod;
        description = descr;
    }
    protected int getCode(int code){
        return code;
    }
    protected String getDescription(String description){
        return description;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\laptopara\Desktop\ask>javac MainFile.java
MainFile.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println((listOfTypes.get(0)).getFixed());
                                       ^        
symbol:   method getFixed()
location: class TypeExpences
1 error
```

If I do System.out.println(waterExp.getFixed()); it works.

How can I make it work with System.out.println((listOfTypes.get(0)).getFixed());?

Answer (score 1):

Ah yea I think your problem is, that you use polymorphic programming...
You have a  object `ArrayList<TypeExpences> listOfTypes`, an `ArrayList` which stores objects of class `TypeExpences`. Thanks to polymorphic programming it's possible to store also objects of sub-classes of `TypeExpences` like `Water`.

Your problem is now, that you can't use methods which are declared in the sub-class `Water`! You can only use methods which are already declared in your base-class `TypeExpences` and I guess the method `public int getFixed()` isn't declared.

Change your code to this...

```
ArrayList <Water> listOfTypes = new ArrayList<Water>();
```

...to fix this issue. Alternate you can implement the method `public int getFixed()` in base-class `TypeExpences` and override it in the sub-class.

Maybe also take a look on this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java) or something like that...

**EDIT**

You can use an interface like this

```
public interface AllMyObjects
{
    public abstract int getFixed();
}
```

Now implement this interface in each class you use like this:

```
public class Water implements AllMyObjects
{
    ...
    @Override public int getFixed()
    {
        return super.getFixedPrice(fixedPrice);
    }
}

...

public class Phone implements AllMyObjects
{
    @Override public int getFixed()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

After this change your array list like this:

```
ArrayList <AllMyObjects> listOfTypes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now its should work if not, write a comment...

Comment: i understand what you are saying but i dont have only Water type of expences in this arraylist. i have also electricity, phone etc. expences and i need to make a arraylist that has all those types and i want to be able to use the specific class methods that they possess even though they are stored in a <TypeExpences> arraylist even though it is a superclass. From what you are saying it isn't possible?